# why are there 3 different names for an Ember initializer

Tags: ember.js

When you generate a service with Ember CLI you get something like this:

```
export function initialize(container, application) {
  application.inject('route', 'geoService', 'service:geo');
  application.inject('component', 'geoService', 'service:geo');
}

export default {
  name: 'geo-service',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

You will notice that includes 3 different name formats for the service - geoService, service:geo and geo-service. Why is this needed and what is each of them? It's pretty confusing this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
export function initialize(container, application) {
  /* service:geo is the factory name for a GeoService object
     the container keeps track of all the factories using this format.
  */

  // inject to every route the GeoService and
  // make it available through the property geoService
  application.inject('route', 'geoService', 'service:geo');

  // inject to every component the GeoService and
  // make it available through the property geoService
  application.inject('component', 'geoService', 'service:geo');
}

export default {
  /*
    The name of your service is geo, but by convention
    all objects are suffixed with the object type name,
    ex:
    ClientsView
    ClientsRoute
    ClientsController
    GeoService

    In Ember CLI The dashed format is the convention
    for file names and names in general.
  */
  name: 'geo-service',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

Ember Data does something like this, so you can use:

```
this.get('store');
```

With your service you can now do:

```
this.get('geoService');
```

Comment: thanks for the good explanation. I still don't know why 2 names are needed - service:geo and geo-service, why not just use one for both purposes?

Comment: `geo-service` is the name of your **object**, you create that; `service:geo` is the name of the **factory**, you do not create that, its part of the internals (container).